# How to fix the error "Links are not crawlable" on my website using WP

Tags: lighthouse

I texted my website on Lighthouse. It alarm me " Links are not crawlable ".

Search engines may use href attributes on links to crawl websites. Ensure that the href attribute of anchor elements links to an appropriate destination, so more pages of the site can be discovered

Uncrawlable Link

How can I fix it?

I have submit the sitemap, and it shows success. but the issues here are still exit.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of reason for link aren’t crawlable

1. If have not any content on your page
2. If have any harmful product review
3. Link rel by "Noindex" tax
4. Roobot.txt problem
5. Technical problem
   If it Technical problem you can index by Google indexing api